# Is it possible to use assign_vertex_id() POLYGONs?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, routing

I'm trying to use pgrouting in order to create a graphe and I have two questions :

**Is it possible to use the function assign_vertex_id() with a POLYGON geometry type?** I always have the following error when I try to use this fonction :

```
psql (9.0.3)
Type "help" for help.

bpi=# SELECT assign_vertex_id('rangee', 0.00001, 'geometrie', 'id');
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"

PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 14 at EXECUTE statement

ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 31 at EXECUTE statement
```

the table rangee is :

```
bpi=# \d rangee

          Table "public.rangee"

    Column    |         Type          | Modifiers
 -------------+-----------------------+-----------
  id          | integer               | not null
  zone_id     | integer               |
  geometrie   | geometry              |
  description | character varying(50) |
  source      | integer               |
  target      | integer               |

Indexes:
 "rangee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
 "rangee_spatial" gist (geometrie)

Triggers:

rangee_geom_srid BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON rangee FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE geometrie_srid()
```

I don't understand this mistake. Could you help me please?

My second question is about pgrouting. **Is it possible to create a dual graph with this tool?**

Thanks a lot  and I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the function assign_vertex_id() with a POLYGON geometry type?

Short answer: No.

Looking at the code at https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/core/sql/routing_topology.sql, the function uses e.g. [ST_StartPoint()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) which only works for LINESTRINGS.

> Is it possible to create a dual graph with this tool?

Not as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) I use the function ST_ExteriorRing and it works

Comment: @raphael happy you found a solution. please use the voting mechanism to reward helpful answers.